# Angular $q returning resolved promise

Tags: angularjs, q, angular-promise

I have a variable `this.eligible` which I would like to assign to the value of a returned promise instead of the actual promise object.

userService

```
this.eligible = this.sweepstakesService.checkUser(data);
```

sweepstakesService

```
checkUser({profileId}) {
var deferred = this.$q.defer();
var id = profileId.replace(/[{}]/g, "");

this.$q.when(this.getGuid(id)
  .then(guid => this.determineEligibility(guid))
  .catch(this.handleError))
  .then(function(data){
      deferred.resolve(data);
});

  return deferred.promise;

}

 getGuid(profileId){
    return this.resourcesService.guid.save({id:profileId}).$promise.then(data => data.guid);
  }

 determineEligibility(response){
      return this.resourcesService.eligibility.save({id:response}).$promise.then(data => data.isEligible);
    }


 handleError(response){
      console.log(response);
  }
```

Currently I'm returning `Promise{$$state: Object}` instead of the actual resolved value.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. `"I have a variable"` _What_ variable?

Comment: I've edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access the result of a promise, you need to provide a callback to the `then` method on the promise object, which will be called asynchronously as soon as the result is available.

```
this.sweepstakesService.checkUser(data)
.then(function(value){
    this.eligible = value;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up with a somewhat elaborate variable definition  this.eligible = this.sweepstakesService.checkUser(data).then((function(data){this.eligible = data}).bind(this));

Answer (score 0):

When you're using **promise**, you're performing some asynchronous request, so you have to pass some **callback** function in order to retrieve your data, and wait for it.

You can use the **$q.defer()** promise manager, from the deferred API.

**$q.defer()** get 2 methods :

- `resolve(value)` : which resolve our associated promise, by giving her the final value
- `reject(reason)` : which resolve an promise error.

Don't forget that you are doing some **asynchronous work**...

Moreover, a good tips can be to **save the current context** into a variable, in order to bind your data.

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, Service) {

  //Save the current context of our controller
  var self = this;

  self.success = '';

  self.fail = '';

  //Declare our promise
  var promise1 = Service.get(2);

  var promise2 = Service.get(6);

  promise1.then(function(response){
    //Retrieve our response and set it to our success variable
    //We use self as our Controller context
    self.success = response;
  }).catch(function(error){
    self.success = error;
  });

  promise2.then(function(response){
    self.fail = response;
  }).catch(function(error){
    //Retrieve our error and set it to our fail variable
    self.fail = error;
  });


}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service($http, $q) {

    function get(n){
      //using $q.defer() from deferred API
      var defer = $q.defer();

      //Simulate latency
      setTimeout(function(){
        n < 3
        ? defer.resolve(n)
        : defer.reject('Error');
      }, 1500);

      //Return our promise
      return defer.promise;

    }

    return {
      get: get
    }

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Service', Service);

})();
```

Then, you can instantiate your controller by using the **controllerAs** syntax.

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl as self'>

    <div>Success : {{self.success}}</div>
    <div>Fail : {{self.fail}}</div>

  </body>
```

You can see an example on this [**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gpeCltQAn3M1zhOVLfTy?p=preview)